# Sending HashMap key through javascript in HTML Thymeleaf form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, thymeleaf

I'm new to front end, and have got one tricky thing I want to solve.
I'm using **MVC** pattern with **HTML/Thymeleaf** and **Java** on the backend side.
I create simple form which has got dynamically adding and removing items from Map. These operations itself are made on a backend side. When you want to add or remove item, you just use javascript which submit form with flag `situationCreateSubmit=false`.
Model which is passing through form looks like:

```
public class SituationRequestModel {
    @Valid
    private SituationModel situation;
    private Boolean situationCreateSubmit=true;
    private Long addInstitutionId;
    private Long removeInstitutionId;
    private Long templateDocumentId;
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] templateDocument;
}
```

So on the backend side, at first the `situationCreateSubmit` field is checking if this form is to be saved to db. If it's false than adding/removing items on the map is made and return to the HTML page. Map itself is field of `SituationModel`.

I managed adding items to the map, but I have a problem with removing items.
I want to have simple row in a table with value from map and link/botton REMOVE to delete this particular row.
[image]

I would like to create jQuery function with some like "onclick" on **Remove** field to assign this particular key of map to the `removeInstitutionId`, set `situationCreateSubmit` to **false** and send it with post like simple submit to the **controller**.

In HTML form I use `foreach` loop through the map:

```
<table class="table table-dark">
     <tbody>
        <tr class="col-12 item-dark" th:each="institution,iter :*{situation.institutions}">
        <td th:text="${institution.value.name}"></td>
        <td><a id="removeinstitution" class="nav-link active"  th:field="${institution.key}" >Remove</a>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

JS which I've wrote looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#removeinstitution").a
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#removeInstitutionId").val(ui.item.key);
            $("#situationCreateSubmit").val(false);
            $( "#situation-create" ).submit();
        }
    });
```

I know it cannot work, but I have no clue how to pass map key to the JS and set it to the `removeInstitutionId` field. I know that in Thymeleaf we can use something like `__institution.key__` which dynamically generate that particular value, but I don't know what to do with that.
**Information**
I don't want to change way of work-> to manipulate with map on the front end side. What I want to have map manipulation logic on the backend side.
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.
Using thymeleaf we can generate dynamicaly **id** for each row in a table. In my case I put HashMap **key** as a id value:

```
<table class="table table-light mt-1">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="col-auto table-active" th:each="institution,iter:*{situation.institutions}">
    <td th:text="${institution.value.name}"></td>
    <td><a th:id="${institution.key}" href="#" class="col-auto remove-institutioncss">Remove</a>
    </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Second functionality is put in JS:

```
$( ".remove-institution-css" ).click(function() {
  $("#removeInstitutionId").val($(this).attr("id"));
  $("#situationCreateSubmit").val(false);
  $( "#situation-create" ).submit();
});
```

Which allows me to: 
1) Assign HashMap **key** (table id) to the object variable `removeInstitutionId`  
2) Set `situationCreateSubmit` flag as false - it's information for backend that form is not ready for saving already.
3) Submit form.

**To remind:** Why do I this way? 
1)I want to have completely HashMap manipulation on the backend side
2)I'm new to HTML/Thymeleaf

Hope it would help anyone.
Regards